# ffmpeg contentiously output stream ("multiplexing")

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, stream

I play for fun with ffmpeg and try to create a cinema like stream.
The idea behind this is to have a contentiously/non ending output stream.

As input i have 2 other streams, which are shown alternating.
For Example, stream0 is the "advertising" input, stream1 the actual movie.

The question is now how do i tell ffmpeg: if stream0 has ended/paused show, stream1.

This is what i have put together:

```js
const cp = require("child_process");
const fs = require("fs");

const intro = fs.createReadStream("./intro.mp4");
const video = fs.createReadStream("./video.mp4");

//intro.pause();
video.pause();

const ffmpeg = cp.spawn("/usr/bin/ffmpeg", [
    "-loglevel", "8", "-hide_banner",
    //"-progress", "pipe:3",
    "-i", "pipe:4", // intro
    "-i", "pipe:5", // video
    //"-map", "0:a",
    //"-map", "1:v",
    "-c:v", "copy",
    //"-filter_complex", "concat=n=3:v=0:a=1",
    "-y",
    `output.mp4`,
], {
    windowsHide: true,
    stdio: [
        "inherit", "inherit", "inherit",
        "pipe", "pipe", "pipe"
    ],
});

ffmpeg.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Merging Completed");
});

setTimeout(() => {

    intro.close();
    video.resume();

}, 1000);

intro.pipe(ffmpeg.stdio[4]);
video.pipe(ffmpeg.stdio[5]);
```

The code above just takes the intro video and write it to "output.mp4". The play/pause behavior described above does not work.

Comment: Closing the pipe when stream is ended but I suppose you want to keep the pipe open, do you?

Comment: @kesh Right, After movie/video has finish played, i want to resume the "intro".